# Python3 shorten absolute windows unc path without using pywin

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, path, unc

I am not able to copy files with too long paths because of windows' limitation (I can't upgrade to a newer Windows 10 version).

I work with absolute UNC pathes and not able to change these restrictions. I am also not able to install pywin.

Is there anyway a solution to shorten the paths so that I can copy file from UNC A to UNC B?

Comment: Shortening the path is possible with symlinks or mapped drives, but it's not the best answer, and relying on legacy DOS 8.3 short names is definitely the wrong idea, if that's what you're thinking, because it's unreliable.

Comment: Long paths are always accessible in the file API as non-normalized device paths that begin with the "\\?\" prefix. UNC paths have to explicitly use the "UNC" device junction. For example, `r"\\server\share\spam"` -> `r"\\?\UNC\server\share\spam"`. Since this path type bypasses normalization, it can only use backslash to separate components, not forward slash.